# #FIELD! in cell but when clicking on cell, the correct value is in the formula box

Tags: excel, field

I have an excel sheet with a large amount of data. Originally the data was in 1 column, separated by a comma, so I have used the test to columns option to get the data spread out, however when I do this, one column is filled with #FIELD! but when I click onto one of those cells, in the formula box it gives the value that should be in that cell.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can display the actual value and get rid of #FIELD! ??

Comment: screen shots would be nice, showing what is in the formula bar of one of the cells that show the error.

Comment: @ScottCraner Added an example above

Comment: Does it still show the error when you change the format of the field value ? What is the current format?

Comment: @IngoSteinke It was in general but ive changed it to both number and accounting and all still show up the FIELD in the cell

Comment: see this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/448376/what-is-the-excel-hotkey-to-re-calculate-all-formula-in-sheet for things to try.

Comment: No, None of those options worked. The value is there before I use the Text to Column option, then it changes to #FIELD!